# Examples on kohonen self organizing maps

Tags: python

Is there a simple example to start with for using [kohonen 1.1.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kohonen) or is it only the [test file](https://github.com/lmjohns3/kohonen/blob/master/kohonen_test.py) that will be the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are alternative solutions](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-good-python-implementations-of-Kohonen-Self-Organizing-Maps-and-Neural-Gas) for self organizing maps.

Best of them I found [pymvpa](http://www.pymvpa.org/examples/som.html) where the example is easy to read and understand. It is also maintained quite activately as you can see from their [Github](https://github.com/PyMVPA/PyMVPA).

I tried to run the kohonen 1.1.2 test file, but it did not run after two days of trying. So, let's have a try for the another solution.

To run pyMVPA example som.py, you have to do the following (at least):

```
1 install some pre-requisites: at least numpy, scipy, nibabel and swig to be able to run setup.py
2 run the commands: 
   python setup.py build
   python setup.py install
3 modify example under doc/examples (som.py) to have 
 import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
4 run command:
   python som.py
```

Note that this works only in python 2, not python3 can be used as command.

Comment: I am not able to build it on my system. It keeps on failing due to Android SDK errors!

Comment: Well, errors tell what is missing. You will need to install them manually.

Comment: :) Sure! I had to run step 2 as sudo. `   python setup.py build
   python setup.py install` and then as you said python 3 it was not working - so one of the installs I had to do `python -m pip install <package>` for Python 2 explicitly. Thanks for the motivation!